# JS script is only working when placed in partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, ckeditor, partial-views

I have a partial view that is loaded via an ajax call. Inside that partial, I have a textarea that is modified by a script. The script is used in other places across the site and is referenced in the _layout page...

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

The script isn't working unless I place it in the partial view.

Its a ckeditor script for what its worth...
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation

This is not specific to this script though - it seems any script that needs to fire onload will fail on a run-time loaded partialview.

I would think that I should leave the script in a universal location like _layout rather than place it both in the _layout and add it to every partial its needed in.

Any ideas?

In my case, the script works by applying a class to a textarea...

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.business.act_comments, new { @class="ckeditor" })
```

Comment: The script may have something like `document.ready` and configure it. So it will work with ajax request & for the editors already available when the page gets loaded first time

Comment: Script may have some functionality which is initialized at loading time. You are loading partial view via AJAX so you need to call same functionality at loading means in document.ready.

Comment: makes sense, but no, there is nothing like that in the script. Maybe there's no harm in including it wherever I need it...